# Recognising output impedance of an amplifier though inspection

Tags: impedance, output, fet

The output impedance of FET amplifiers seem to be a hit and miss affair when I try to find it just through inspection. For example, sometimes it's easy to predict, whereas some other times I have to go through very tiring circuit analysis just to get it; and my answer through inspection seems to be way off from the actual value. For example, the common gate amplifier has an output impedance of \$1/g_{m}\$ which wasn't intuitive at all.

So, I wonder if there's a way that one can tell from inspection because its possible that the way I'm inspecting things is wrong.

Comment: Usually these things are used with negative feedback around them, so the apparent output impedance (until limits of voltage or current are violated) will be mostly a function of the open loop and closed loop gains.  The physical impedance of the actual transistors goes to dictating the limits, but don't effect impedance much until a limit is reached.

Comment: Maybe try showing a few small circuits - I believe most of them are fairly clear cut but some can be tricky.

Comment: horemheb, please note that the mentioned quantity 1/gm is NOT the output but the input resistance in common gate configuration. (See also my detailed answer).

Answer (score 1):

I often deal with this problem, it's not trivial.

Many times there are local feedbacks. In that case, you can avoid complicated equations.

1. Find the cold resistance \$R_{out}^0\$. That is without considering the feedback.
2. By visual inspection, look at how the feedback behaves. Will it increase the current drawn in response to your voltage stimulus? If yes, that means it will decrease the resistance, so the output resistance will be $$R_{out} = \frac{R_{out}^0}{1 - G_{loop}}$$

The reality is that you can't do the basic stuff all over again every time you analyze a circuit. At some point, you just have to remember a few formulas, especially since there's only a few basic configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a transistor level design guy.  (The only useful way for me to use a transistor is to wrap an opamp around it.)  Unless there's a big resistor in series on the output I can't guess the output impedance. (Well Vthermal/Ic if bipolar)  But I have measured it.  And you quickly find out that the output impedance of an opamp is complex.  And sometimes you care about the complex impedance and sometimes just the resistive (real) part.  Good opamps will sometimes have graphs, but then you have to look at the measurement circuit to figure out what they are showing you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your question mainly concerns non-linear circuits (with BJT`s, FET`s,...). In this case, it is indeed not a simple task to estimate the value of the output resistance because in many cases - as mentioned already by O. Lathrop - such circuits will contain feedback loops that are connected at the output node.

In such a case, the approximate value of the (dynamic, differential) output resistance r,out can be approximately determined if you know the output resistance without feedback (ro) and the loop gain A,loop of the circuit: **r,out=ro/(1-A,loop)**. (Note that for negative feedback the loop gain has a negative value).

In your example (common gate/base amplifier) you have mentioned **1/gm** which is the **input** resistance. This resistance can be easily found by inspection. You simply have to find the signal voltage-to-current ratio at the source/emitter node (gate/base grounded) which is known from the classical common source/emitter configuration:

Output current (I,source; I,emitter)=gm*input voltage (V,GS; VBE).

In common gate/base configuration the input voltage remains the same and the "output" current turns into input current. Hence: input voltage/input current=**1/gm**.

(At the same time, this is the transistor`s ouput resistance in common drain/collector configuration)

The output resistance r,o in common gate/base configuration (without feedback) is nearly identical to the output resistance in common source/emitter and is mainly determind by the resistor Rd (Rc) that is connected at the output node.